# NSPredicate (filterContentForSearchText) if/else: searchText hasPrefix:@"#"

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, full-text-search, nspredicate

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
  if ([searchText hasPrefix:@"#"]) {
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(def contains[c] %@)", searchText];
    searchResults = [chengduhua filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
  } else {
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(head beginswith[c] %@) OR (pro beginswith[c] %@) OR (searchableStringValue beginswith[c] %@)", searchText, searchText, searchText];
    searchResults = [chengduhua filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
  }
}
```

My `else` is working fine, but any `#` prefixed searches turn up empty.

Any hints?

Is searchText the right thing I need to be prefixing?!

Here's my search display controller:

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                           scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                  objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                 selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't strip the stupid prefix.

Here's my solution

```
    NSString *prefixToRemove =@"#";
    NSString *newString = [searchText copy];
    if ([searchText hasPrefix:prefixToRemove])
        newString = [searchText substringFromIndex:[prefixToRemove length]];
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(def contains[c] %@)", newString];
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find this fixes it :

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(def contains[c] '%@')", searchText];
```

(Note the addition of quotation marks around the %@)